# selecting from multiple tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql

table 1

```
id | question
1  | who will win the election
```

table 2

```
id | answers | question id
1  | I will  | 1
```

table 3

```
id | photo | question id
1  | xy.gif| 1
```

table 4 * users can both suggest questions and vote for others

```
id | username
1  | joe
```

table 5

```
id | vote | question_id | user_id
1  | He   | 1           | 1
```

What is the query that will get me the following information in one query

- t1.* (all the questions)
- t2 all the answers connected to the questions
- t3 all the photos related to the questions
- t4 usernames of the author for each question
- t5 the votes for the questions (it is possible that some questions will not have a vote of the logged in user)
- my problem is the last point, getting the votes (while not all questions have votes by the specific logged user)

Here is how my query looks like:

```
            SELECT 
        poll_questions.id,
        poll_questions.question,
        poll_questions.qmore,
        poll_questions.total_votes,
        poll_questions.active,
        poll_questions.created_at,
        poll_answers.answer,
        poll_answers.votes,
        poll_answers.id AS answer_id,
        poll_photos.photo_name_a,
        vote_history_raw.vote,
        users.username

        FROM poll_questions 

        LEFT JOIN (poll_answers, poll_photos)  
            ON (poll_answers.question_id = poll_questions.id AND
                poll_photos.question_id = poll_questions.id
                )
        LEFT JOIN users ON poll_questions.author = users.id 

        INNER JOIN vote_history_raw ON users.id = vote_history_raw.user_id 

        WHERE poll_questions.active = 1 

        ORDER BY poll_questions.created_at DESC
```

thanks much!

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't get the vote_history_raw.vote to join on both the question_id and the user_id

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it, but does this work?

```
  SELECT 
    poll_questions.id,
    poll_questions.question,
    poll_questions.qmore,
    poll_questions.total_votes,
    poll_questions.active,
    poll_questions.created_at,
    poll_answers.answer,
    poll_answers.votes,
    poll_answers.id AS answer_id,
    poll_photos.photo_name_a,
    vote_history_raw.vote,
    users.username

    FROM poll_questions 

    LEFT JOIN (poll_answers, poll_photos)  
        ON (poll_answers.question_id = poll_questions.id AND
            poll_photos.question_id = poll_questions.id
            )
    LEFT JOIN users ON poll_questions.author = users.id 

    LEFT JOIN vote_history_raw ON (users.id = vote_history_raw.user_id OR users.id <> vote_history_raw.user_id AND vote_history_raw.user_id IS NOT NULL)

    WHERE poll_questions.active = 1 

    ORDER BY poll_questions.created_at DESC
```

Comment: No it didn't - the LEFT join you modified has users.id in it, but it needs to be the current user id not the question author user_id - I tried changing it to one the users I have in the db without posts (replaced users.id in your join with #13) but it didn't work